How to access another field in springs @Value
like the title suggests I want to access another fields value using springs @Value annotation.
I want to do this to resolve the fields value by another fields id. Eg.: I have a field id and a field idContent. The idContent field should be automatically created by a method call to another bean using the id fields value.
I tried something like this:
public class MyBean {

    // This is set beforehand
    private final String id;

    @Value("#{otherBean.resolve(#id)}")
    private SomeObject idObject;

}

I get the following message back: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed

This could be done in plain java using constructor injection instead of field injection
@Component
public class MyBean {
   private final String id;
   private final SomeObject idObject;

   public MyBean(@Value("${id}") String id, OtherBean otherBean) {
      this.id = id;
      this.idObject = otherBean.resolve(id);
   }

   ...
}

Another option is to implement InitializingBean
@Component
public class MyBean implements InitializingBean {
   @Value("${id}")
   private String id;

   @Autowired
   private OtherBean otherBean;

   private SomeObject idObject;

   @Override
   public void afterPropertiesSet() {
      this.idObject = otherBean.resolve(id);
   }
}

I personally dislike field injection and always use constructor injection and final fields.
